# Aggregating data in a single table with Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Using Django, I want to generate a queryset with some daily statistics by aggregating from a table with multiple entries per day.  Here's the table

```
CREATE TABLE weather
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  air_temp double precision NOT NULL,
  obs_date date,
  ....
)
```

This is the SQL equivalent of the result I want to get this in the queryset

```
select obs_date, avg(air_temp) from weather group by obs_date order by obs_date
```

The Django model looks like this

```
class WeatherData(models.Model):

    obs_date = models.DateField('Obs Date', blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
    air_temp = models.FloatField('Air Temp', blank=False, null=False)
    ...
```

I've read this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/  but can't see how to do it.  Suggestions appreciated.

Update: this works:

```
WeatherData.objects.values('obs_date').annotate( max_air=Max('air_temp'), min_air=Min('air_temp'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
somedata = WeatherData.objects.annotate(Avg('air_temp')).order_by('obs_date')
for datum in somedata:
  print '%s: %s' % (datum.obs_date, datum.air_temp__avg)
```

Comment: This didn't work, but it put me on the right track.  Where this goes wrong is all the fields in the table end up in the GROUP BY generated by Django.  If you insert .values() before the annotate you get the right result